# Examine the file content being uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

> I'd like to get both C# and VB.NET sugestion.

I have an ASP.NET FileUpload control, which allows only image type. I used RegularExpressionValidator like below.

```
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fuPhoto" runat="server" TabIndex="40" />
        &nbsp;<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" 
                runat="server" ControlToValidate="fuPhoto" Display="Dynamic" 
                ErrorMessage="* You can only upload .jpg, .gif or .png image types." 
                ValidationExpression="^.*\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)$">* You can only upload .jpg, .gif or .png image types.</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

This method will only verify the file's extension, not its actual type. Once I receive the file, I want to examine its contents to determine what it really is, in this case image only.

How do I examine the file content being uploaded?

Comment: What method are you using to prove the content is a valid image file? File headers are fine, but steganography relies on presenting a valid appearing file. Sounds like you need to redefine the business need ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that regular expression is wrong because it prevents me uploading jpg's. In any case you can check the content type on the server using something like:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string filename in Request.Files)
            Response.Write("<p>" + Request.Files[filename].ContentType + "</p>");
    }
```

Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type for valid types